# gl.getBufferSubData not working with ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, webgl2

I'm trying to read data from a buffer using gl.getBufferSubData, I followed the [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext/getBufferSubData)

```
let position_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, position_buffer);
let positions = [
    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let arrBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(positions.length * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
gl.getBufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, arrBuffer);
```

But I'm getting this error (both on Firefox and Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: WebGL2RenderingContext.getBufferSubData: Argument 3 does not implement interface ArrayBufferView.
```

Comment: An ArrayBuffer is not an ArrayBufferView, you need to pass this method a TypedArray, e.g a Float32Array. That example from MDN would need a revision...

Comment: I can't find any documentation/working example on this, I'm also getting this warning `WebGL warning: getBufferSubData: Reading from a buffer with usage other than *_READ causes pipeline stalls. Copy through a STREAM_READ buffer.`

Comment: Yes this whole example is completely wrong. I am not an expert myself in webgl2, so I can't rewrite that example, but I'll open an issue. [And here is an other & better example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices#non-blocking_async_data_downloadreadback).